# Symfony 3 DTOOneCommand changing null value to 0 after handleRequest

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dto, symfony-3.4

I am working on a Symfony 3 project and I am facing a problem. When my form is submitted it changed the value from `null` to `zero`. But I would like that it keeps value it is sent. Because for me `null` is different than `0`.

I have dump like (form use create form from `scenarioProposalVersionModelizeCommand`):

```
    dump($scenarioProposalVersionModelizeCommand->phaseProposalVersions[0]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    dump($scenarioProposalVersionModelizeCommand->phaseProposalVersions[0]);die;
```

Output so this 3 last values as you can see are transformed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going over the problem by using directly information from request.

Using php condition to treat the `value: ""`

```
if(empty($value) && strlen($value) == 0)
  $value = null;
```

But question is still valid.